# Prevent user from changing primary email address while being a member of a GitHub organization

Tags: github, github-organizations

Is there a way to prevent the user from accessing the GitHub organization if the user changes his primary email address? Currently even if the user is invited to the organization using a particular email address, the user can change his primary email address and still be able to access the organization.

Comment: why is that a problem?

Comment: Our team invite users based on their work email address. They shouldn't be able to access the organization if they no longer have access to that email address. Of course we can remove them from organization whenever we want. But we expect them to use the email address using which we invited them as long as they are still a member of the organization .

Comment: In that case it sounds like your aims are directly incompatible with the concept of invited/guest users in the first place - In that case you should create new user accounts in your own GitHub Organization for those users instead of expecting them to restrict their usage of their own personal accounts.